# Using JQUERY slideToggle from same DIV classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, slidetoggle

I have been searching this site for the solution, but I can't see it. I have a problem with slideToggle from same DIV class ID.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.yeah").click(function(){
   $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

### my code doesnt work

```
<div class="yeah"><a href="#">Menu 1</a><br />
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</div>


<div class="yeah"><a href="#">Menu 2</a><br />
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</div>


<div class="yeah"><a href="#">Menu 3</a><br />
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</div>
```

How can I toggle each one of these separately without changing the HTML, only jquery is allowed to change.

Answer (score 1):

The `ul` node is inside the `div` node, not next to it :

```
$("div.yeah").click(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: To the Questioner, you should pick the answer as respect to the answer-maker ;)

Answer (score 0):

`next()` expects to search for siblings, so the same level:
http://api.jquery.com/next/

Instead you can do:

```
$(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
```

Because `find` will look **inside** of the div.

Also, you should close your `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

First up, your DOM code is wrong(no close tag for ul)

Second I assume you need to access the ul inside the div, child('ul') instead of next('ul') since ul is a child element and they are not on the same level.

Comment: thank you sir, sorry I forgot to close it here, but the original html UL tag is closed